Pydantic model_json_schema updated field description
I am trying to update the descriptions of fields in my class such that the original field description is changed from what is defined in the Field function. The example code is below, unfortunately when I call model_json_schema it still prints out Meatball.
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class A(BaseModel):
    @classmethod
    def update_description(cls, field_name: str, new_description: str):
        if field_name in cls.model_fields:
            cls.model_fields[field_name].description = new_description

        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Field '{field_name}' does not exist in {cls.__name__}")

class B(A):
    J: str = Field(description="MEATBALL")

B.update_description('J', 'Updated')


b_instance = B(J="A")
print(b_instance.model_json_schema()) 


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When using pydantic the Pydantic Field function assigns the field descriptions at the time of class creation or class initialization like the __init__(). It will show the model_json_schema() as a default JSON object of some sort, which shows the initial description you mentioned this is because because the schema is cached.
Having said that I have modified your code to help you.
See docs on cls.model_rebuild()
rom pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class A(BaseModel):
    @classmethod
    def update_description(cls, field_name: str, new_description: str):
        if field_name in cls.__fields__:
            cls.__fields__[field_name].field_info.description = new_description
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Field '{field_name}' does not exist in {cls.__name__}")

    @classmethod
    def model_json_schema(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.model_json_schema()
        return super().model_json_schema(*args, **kwargs)


class B(A):
    J: str = Field(description="MEATBALL")


# Update the field description
B.update_description("J", "Updated")

# Create an instance and print the JSON schema
b_instance = B(J="A")
print(b_instance.schema())
 

Result of Test:
{'title': 'B', 'type': 'object', 'properties': {'J': {'title': 'J', 'description': 'Updated', 'type': 'string'}}, 'required': ['J']}


Hey Derek, It didn't seem to load "Updated" into the description field. I still get "MEATBALL"

hmm, interesting I have updated the code let see what happens.

The model_json_schema is recursive and would not work and the pydantic in the new version you've sent is pydantic v1.

Please Can you run my code above and provide the error message you are seeing?

It looks promising, but doesn't work. After removing the line cls.model_json_schema() the recursion error is gone. But still, it doesn't work and the schema is not updated. Also, I replaced .schema() with .model_json_schema()
